# How to get out of a blue screen on a Mac Mini

Tags: mac

I did a system update yesterday and there was only one, which was for my Epson printer. Today on reboot, I get a blue screen with a revolving disk. I managed to get my installation disk in and pressed the <kbd>C</kbd> button but nothing. I rebooted and held the mouse key but the DVD does not want to come out. I have a windows wireless keyboard and I have held down every key possible but still no luck.

I have had this Mac Mini with Snow Leopard 10.6.8 for about 7 years now but I think it has finally had it. Any ideas please before i buy a new pc?

Comment: Try using a keyboard with a physical connection.  This eliminates any possibility that it is a wireless connection issue.

Answer (score 0):

From CNet:

> The likely cause is a corrupt system file which can be cured by
>   booting the mini from the OS X installation disk, or the Recovery Disk
>   that came with the mini, and running an Archive and Install of the
>   system. Prior to doing that, and after you have booted the machine
>   from an external disk, run the disk utility that you will find on the
>   OS X installation disk. If all is well, proceed with the Archive and
>   Install.
>
> Archive and Install will preserve all your data while replacing the
>   system.

If the internal disk drive does not work you can try booting from an external one.

Comment: i am waiting for my wife to come in as she might know where my wired keyboard is,as i say my installation disk is in the mac and i have tried holding the c button so it boots from it but no luck,i bought an external dvd writer for the mac a few weeks ago so if i can get the installation disk out i could try that,i have held the mouse button on reboot to try to get the dvd out but no luck ?

Comment: When you turn the computer off and back on, do you see a grey screen come up with an Apple logo?  If you do, we can continue.  If not, the answer here MAY help:
http://superuser.com/questions/23810/mac-mini-wont-boot-and-wont-fix

Comment: CNet mentioned an eternal drive and i have just found a copy of my installation disk,i went to utility and i am repairing permissions at the moment and then i will do an archive and install,i will post after completion

Comment: i did a disk repair and i am currently re-installing my system.